# How to fetch multiple images of any given format from nestjs backend that can be rendered on postman for testing

Tags: image, image-processing, nestjs, fetch

I am trying to make a service where a user can search for images. The service can handle all the image formats. It should return the images based on the search keyword provided. The result can be single/multiple or no images if no match is found. below is the code snippet of nestjs controller and service used for this. Please help me out here as I can't seem to find any relevant resource for fetching. Only got solution for uploading which is done. Thanks in advance.

**controller:-
**

```
@Get('image')
  async getUserProfilePhoto(
    @Query('searchTerm') searchTerm: string,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response,
  ) {

    console.log('controller log', searchTerm);

    return await this.appService.fetchImages(searchTerm, res);
  }
```

**service for multiple images:-
**

```
async fetchImages(keyword: string, res: Response) {
    const searchRegex = new RegExp(keyword, 'i');
    const uploadPath = join(process.cwd(), 'upload');
    const files = await readdir(uploadPath);
    console.log('files', files);
    const matchingImages = [];
    for (const file of files) {
      const fileExtension = extname(file);
      const fileNameWithoutExtension = file.replace(fileExtension, '');

      if (searchRegex.test(fileNameWithoutExtension)) {
        const filePath = join(uploadPath, file);
        console.log('filePath', filePath);

        const stats = statSync(filePath);

        if (stats.isFile()) {
          matchingImages.push({
            fileName: file,
            filePath: filePath,
          });
        }
      }
    }
    if (matchingImages.length > 0) {
      
      res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'image/*' });

      
      for (const image of matchingImages) {
        const fileStream = createReadStream(image.filePath);
        fileStream.pipe(res, { end: false });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('No matching images found');
    }
  }
```

**console log outputs:-
**
controller log wll
files [
'wllp.jpeg',
'wllp_150x97.png',
'wllp_300x194.png',
'wllp_450x291.png',
'wllp_600x388.png',
'wllp_750x485.png'
]
filePath /home/agilepc109/Pawan/ImageServiceTask/ImageService/upload/wllp.jpeg
filePath /home/agilepc109/Pawan/ImageServiceTask/ImageService/upload/wllp_150x97.png
filePath /home/agilepc109/Pawan/ImageServiceTask/ImageService/upload/wllp_300x194.png
filePath /home/agilepc109/Pawan/ImageServiceTask/ImageService/upload/wllp_450x291.png
filePath /home/agilepc109/Pawan/ImageServiceTask/ImageService/upload/wllp_600x388.png
filePath /home/agilepc109/Pawan/ImageServiceTask/ImageService/upload/wllp_750x485.png

expectation:-

the images at the filepaths should be rendered on postman.

what happening is:-

a file is getting downloaded directly with no data in it.

service code for single image which is rendered successfully on postman:-

```js
async fetchImages(keyword: string, res: Response) {
    const searchRegex = new RegExp(keyword, 'i');
    const uploadPath = join(process.cwd(), 'upload');
    const files = await readdir(uploadPath);
    console.log('files', files);
    const matchingImages = [];
    for (const file of files) {
      const fileExtension = extname(file);
      const fileNameWithoutExtension = file.replace(fileExtension, '');

      if (searchRegex.test(fileNameWithoutExtension)) {
        const filePath = join(uploadPath, file);
        console.log('filePath', filePath);

        const stats = statSync(filePath);

        if (stats.isFile()) {
          const contentType = `image/${fileExtension.substring(1)}`;
          res.set({ 'Content-Type': contentType });

          const fileStream = createReadStream(filePath);

          return new StreamableFile(fileStream);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please read the tags that you add. This had nothing to do with [the Processing programming language](https://processing.org).